Fast bulk insert with on_conflict_do_nothing in sqlalchemy using postgresql database
sqlalchemy version: 2.0.36
postgresql version from docker image: postgres:15-alpine
First I used psycopg2 in python to create bul insert like so:

    sql = """INSERT INTO ego_pose(token, translation, rotation, timestamp)
        VALUES %s ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;"""
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        sql_args_batch = [
            (
                ego_pose["token"],
                ego_pose["translation"],
                ego_pose["rotation"],
                ego_pose["timestamp"],
            )
            for ego_pose in ego_poses
        ]
        execute_values(cur, sql, sql_args_batch)

I wanted to move to sqlalchemy and created EgoPose class and this insert from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql:
 session.execute(Insert(EgoPose).on_conflict_do_nothing(), dataset.ego_pose) # dataset.ego_pose is list of ego_pose dictionary


Unfortunately I want to insert thousands of rows and with second option it takes much longer. What am I doing wrong?
Update 1: more information

Number of rows to insert is 2631083
Old table is created by:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ego_pose (
    token UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    translation NUMERIC(15, 10) [3] NOT NULL,
    rotation NUMERIC(15, 10) [4] NOT NULL,
    timestamp BIGINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (token)
);


It took 2 min 19 sec
With sqlalchemy it lloks like this:

class EgoPose(Base):
    __tablename__ = "ego_pose"
    token: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, nullable=False)
    translation: Mapped[List[float]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(Numeric(20, 10)), nullable=False)
    rotation: Mapped[List[float]] = mapped_column(ARRAY(Numeric(20, 10)), nullable=False)
    timestamp: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(BigInteger, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<EgoPose(token={self.token}>"


It took 3 min 16 sec
some logs:

2024-11-28 09:21:55,262 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 12.57689s (insertmanyvalues) 1/26311 (unordered)] {'token__0': 'bddd80ae33ec4e32b27fdb3c1160a30e', 'timestamp__0': 1531883530440378, 'rotation__0': [-0.7504501527141022, -0.0076295847961364415, 0.00847103369020136, -0.6608287216181199], 'translation__0': [1010.1273947164545, 610.7727090350685, 0.0], 'token__1': '90df03ad4710427aabb5f88fe049df2e', 'timestamp__1': 1531883530510442, 'rotation__1': [-0.743742073537717, -0.007726799292098994, 0.008375154888041067, -0.6683695694771852], 'translation__1': [1010.1677992044663, 611.0752573625425, 0.0], 'token__2': '28e6129458c745dbbcbdbb3329e91575', 'timestamp__2': 1531883530585295, 'rotation__2': [-0.7360977621773152, -0.007751210095172378, .....
2024-11-28 09:21:55,385 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO ego_pose (token, translation, rotation, timestamp) VALUES (%(token__0)s::UUID, %(translation__0)s::NUMERIC(20, 10)[], %(rotation__0)s::NUMERIC(20, 10)[], %(timestamp__0)s), (%(token__1)s::UUID, %(translation__1)s::NUMERIC(20, 10)[], %(rot ... 11601 characters truncated ... s::NUMERIC(20, 10)[], %(rotation__99)s::NUMERIC(20, 10)[], %(timestamp__99)s) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
2024-11-28 09:21:55,385 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [insertmanyvalues 2/26311 (unordered)] {'...


After running new tests I think it is ok like is. I just got frustrated after 2x10h sessions of debugging but ultimately the most time consuming thing was in different tables and it had nothing to do with sqlalchemy.

I tested different insertmanyvalues_page_size parameter sizes and it changes how many insert_many_values there are but I did not see a difference in time.

dataset.ego_pose just gives list of dictionaries to insert just like in first example in O(1) time.

I think after all this I will take today off work.

I would like to thank people in the comments who took they time in  running their experiments.

The question still remains if you can get it even faster. Around 40% slower is fine when it takes minutes but maybe there is still something I can do.



This question is missing information: 1) The contents of the EgoPose class. 2) What is dataset? 3) What the Postgres log shows is happening when run the SQLAlchemy code? Add as text update to question text.

I tried both methods using 1000000 rows o random data and the SQLAlchemy approach from the question was about 20% slower.  Is the difference in duration that you experience similar?  More? Less?

@snakecharmerb - IIRC with bulk ORM insert, insertmanyvalues uses (defaults to?) a batch size of 1_000 rows, so 1_000_000 rows would generate 1_000 insert statements. Did the DBAPI-only approach send a single insert statement with all of the rows in one big "blob"?

@GordThompson according to the psycopg2 docs, the default page size for execute_values is 100.  I did try different page sizes in SQLA, but they didn't seem to make much difference.

Have you tried using a constraint in on_conflict_do_nothing? Try this: session.execute(sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.insert(EgoPose).values([{...}]).on_conflict_do_nothing(constraint=EgoPose.__table__.primary_key))

I think you need to read Insert Many Values. In particular the section Controlling the Batch Size.

If I needed maximum speed I would investigate using pgcopy to upload the rows to a temporary table and then run INSERT INTO ego_pose … SELECT … FROM my_temp_table ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
